# Html Css overflowing to right side of the page

Tags: html, css

I think problem is `div.ü` and `div.yayın` is overflowing the right side of the page when I delete these its not happening. Can I use another position code or something ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeIbV.jpg]

```css
div.ü{
    
    position:relative;
    left:10%;
    vertical-align:top;}

div.yayın{
    
    position:relative;
    left:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ü">
       <a href="#">Yayın Akışı</a>


</div>


<div class="yayın">
  <br>
  <a href = "http://localhost/php/sistemler/haber.php">
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" class=""   height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de Fi"</h3>
  </a>
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" class=""   height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de rm"</h3>
  
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" class=""   height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>
  
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" class=""   height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>
  
  
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: your class `ü` do not exist... plus it is not use in a div but in a `img`. Plus you have 2 elements `class` into your img.

Comment: @disinfor could you explain about left taking the element out of the normal document flow? It seems to keep the element in the normal document flow from my experiments.

Comment: If you use any position properties, the element will not affect any other element around it. What experiments have you tried? Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/a91qom0y/1/

Comment: left:10% puts it 10% offset and it overflows unless you reduce width to about 90% (mind too `box-sizing`,`margin`,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 error in your css:

- Your div with class `ü` does not exist
- It is not used on a div but on an image.
- You have 2 class attributes on your image.

Then add this `max-width:90%;` if you really need to use `left:10%;` to your css as below:

```
div.yayın{ 
  position:relative;
  left:10%;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

And replace `left: 10%;` by `margin-left:10%;` in class `yay1n`.

### DEMO

```css
div .u{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:10%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

div.yayın{ 
  position:relative;
  left:10%;
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yayın">
  <br>
  <a href = "http://localhost/php/sistemler/haber.php">
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de Fi"</h3>
  </a>
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de rm"</h3>
  
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>
  
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src = "images/7.jpg" height = "125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>
  
  
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using `left: 10%`. Using `left, right, top, bottom` takes the element out of normal document flow and the element will not affect any other element. Use `margin-left: 10%` instead.

```css
div.u {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.yayın {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yayın">
  <br>
  <a href="http://localhost/php/sistemler/haber.php">
    <h3><img class="u" src="images/7.jpg" class="" height="125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de Fi"</h3>
  </a>
  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src="images/7.jpg" class="" height="125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de rm"</h3>

  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src="images/7.jpg" class="" height="125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>

  <br>
  <h3><img class="u" src="images/7.jpg" class="" height="125px" style="margin-right:20px;">Section 1.10.33 of "de um"</h3>




</div>
```